# How to disable form submit in my case

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to disable the submit action when a user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <form name="form1" class="form-horizontal"
 onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;"
 ng-submit="submitForm()">
   <div class="form-group">
     <div>Test here</div>                                            
     <textarea ng-model="message" rows="3"></textarea>
   </div>
 </div>
```

The `onkeypress` attribute will make the form NOT get submitted when user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>; however, the user won't be able to have breakline in the `textarea` element. In other words, the user can only keep typing without break even if they hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this: `ng-submit="submitForm()"` Add a button to the form to do the submission through `ng-click="submitForm()`. All forms should have a button to submit with, so that should take care of your issue. Use `type="button"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Since you're using Angular:

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```